# iOS In App Purchases Not Showing Up In App Store Build

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

I'm having an issue where my recently approved iOS app isn't showing any in-app purchases. My TestFlight build works, and all the in app purchases were approved with my initial submission. To grab the products I'm running:

```
        let productIDs = // ...
        let customProductsRequest = SKProductsRequest(productIdentifiers: productIDs)
        customProductsRequest.delegate = self
        customProductsRequest.start()
```

Once in-app purchases are approved and my app is "Ready for Sale" do I need to do anything else to get the purchases to show up? My apps been live for a bit over an hour now. I reverified with a new TF build and they work in that build.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm guessing that this is a propagation issue. I've experienced apps in the past where it has taken more than six hours for the in app purchases to propagate. If everything works in the TestFlight builds it should be the same in production.

Comment: Thank god, this scared the ever living tits mcgee out of me

Comment: @Tallboy Yeah - definitely a 'feature' that has lead to a few developer heart attacks.